# php, jQuery, Lightbox, Ajax GET and POST issue

Tags: php, jquery, post, get, lightbox

I have a form in a lightbox (fancybox).
I am trying to do an ajax get to run an update to the database.
But I do not know why it does not work.
The code below is what is in the lightbox:

```
<div id="timezonelightbox">

<div class="lightboxtitle">Select Time Zone</div>

<form method="get" action="" >

<select name="timezones" id="timezones" class="selecttimezones">

<option value="Africa/Abidjan   ">Africa/Abidjan    </option>

<option value="Africa/Accra     ">Africa/Accra  </option>

<option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa   ">Africa/Addis_Ababa    </option>

<option value="Africa/Algiers   ">Africa/Algiers    </option>

<option value="Africa/Asmara">Africa/Asmara</option>

</select>

<input type="button" id="confirmtimezone" class="confirmtimezone" value="Confirm now" 
onclick="updateTimeZone(); $.fancybox.close();">
</form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

        function updateTimeZone(){

                $.getScript('<?echo $site["url"];?>/updateTimeZone.php?timezones=<?echo $_GET["timezones"]?>');

}

        </script>
```

This is what I have in the called file:

```
header("content-type:text/js");

if(isset($_GET['timezones'])){

$queryupdatetimezone="UPDATE `Profiles` SET `TimeZone` ='".$_GET['timezones']."' WHERE 
ID=".(int)$_COOKIE['memberID'];

$resultupdatetimezone=mysql_query($queryupdatetimezone) or die("Errore update default timezones: ".mysql_error());

    exit;

}else{

?>alert ('An error occured');<?

}
?>
```

Everything seems fine when I click the confirm button. No errors. But when I look in the database it saves an empty string. $_GET['timezones'] is empty. How is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: to write code here: multiline: intend each line at least 4 spaces. For inline-code enclose your code with `  = `test`

Comment: Wow, ain't this question of the day

Comment: @DiegoP, on the right side, while you are posing your question or editing question are the information about writing effective question.

Comment: You tell us to solve this for you but the problem you are having isn't even near the code you are showing us, What form is sending it to this? What url's are you using? and srsly... the capslock part is like shouting for attention, please dont do that... Honestly, I can't help you, please provide a more complete code of both the form page and the receiving page... As far as the html part... Maybe you should just learn how the ajax, php and other code you use work

Comment: @DiegoP, I am not going to edit your question any more than this.

Comment: I don't think the problem is me! I think the problem is that this site is too difficult to understand. Yes you are Great! You always have the right answer, but asking a question is just a nightmare. You need a vocabulary to understand what to do when adding a new question. Anyway all the code I have is there. The HTML form you see there is shown inside a lightbox. When the button is clicked the ajax function should run by calling the php file and passing the "timezones" data from the select box. Is that so difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an emtry string, because you are sending an empty string. Look at this line you posted:

```
$.getScript('/updateTimeZone.php?timezones=');
```

You probably forgot to give the timezone you wanted into there like this:

```
$.getScript('/updateTimeZone.php?timezones=THE_TIMEZONE');
```

Replace `THE_TIMEZONE` with the timezone you want to set...

Comment: sorry but this is not the problem. The value from the select box is there. It does not work propably because the code is wrong. I am not an experienced programmer, I just play with the code. I know the most difficult things sometime, and I do not know the simplest ones in some other times. This is my problem. Thank you

Comment: @Diego: The problem is that you create the value of timezones when the server renders the page. The value which is selected by the user is _ignored_. Analyze the situation and think about which parts of your code are executed at which time - when the server sends the page, or when the user interacts with it.