# Get selected value and send that by ajax onclick

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the second time I ask this question because in my first try I was totally misunderstood.

[php, jQuery, Lightbox, Ajax GET and POST issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990378/php-jquery-lightbox-ajax-get-and-post-issue)

What I am trying to achieve is simply to get the selected value from a dropdown list and send that by an ajax function to a php file that will run the necessary functions. So let's say I select Africa/Accra as timezone, onclick the ajax function is called and that will pass the data to the php file that will do the rest. No page refresh, nothing, just getting the data and send that with ajax. Is this possible? please to better understand me see my first try (link above).
I am not an experienced PHP programmer. I do not know about anything of Ajax, so propably I have just done everything wrong..so forgive me. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [php, jQuery, Lightbox, Ajax GET and POST issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990378/php-jquery-lightbox-ajax-get-and-post-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what you want:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
    var selectedValue = $("#IdOfDropdown").val();
    $.get("test.php", { timezone: selectedValue } , function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

You can also do a post instead of a get, here is a reference with a bunch of jquery ajax stuff
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: I think this is gonna work. Now I am just confused how to achieve this. I need to put the value in the url. so it will look like $.get("test.php?timezone=selectedvalue"). How do I do it? Thanks again

Comment: I've edited the code to for your particular scenario. Give that a try. You dont need to assemble the url with the values in it, the jQuery GET function will do that for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it now. Just a little change, I repeat, I do not know anything about ajax..can I remove the alert? How? Thanks.

Comment: $.get("test.php", { timezone: selectedValue }); replaces the 3 lines before the return statement

Comment: No problem, gave me something to do until I went home =)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value you could use Javascript or Jquery.

In javascript you can say:

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById("selectId");
selectedValue.options[selectedValue.selectedIndex].value;
```

Afterwards try and see how these guys do it:
[AJAX TO PHP](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html?page=2)

This is one way to do it. The AJAX call could look different, but try and se if this solves your problem. :)

//Gerner